# How to get value from "dynamic row field" column to another field in system.xml. How to compare this with Order Subtotal after proceed to checkout

Tags: magento2.4, validation, system.xml

[image: Module Configuration]

How can to get value of "price" column in "custom Alert Message" Field.
here is system.xml code `

```
<field id="ranges" translate="label" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Set Tax</label>
                    <frontend_model>MyCompany\Order\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Ranges</frontend_model>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
                </field>
                 <field id="alert_message" translate="label" type="textarea" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Custom Alert Message</label>
                    <comment>Enter custom alert message .</comment>
                    
                </field>`
```

How can I get "price" field value from system.xml and "Customer group", when customer clicks "Proceed to checkout" and then compare the value with order subtotal. and on the basis of it how to sieze "checkout process" and redirect customer to "checkout/cart/" so that he can update order to match the validation.

Comment: Do you want fetch those value into some where else into code or into same system.xml?

Comment: In system.xml.And then at checkout also

Comment: But why you needed that into system.xml? Because that are multiple values that why.

Comment: I only need value of One column which is "Price".

Answer (score 0):

To get those fields value on fronted, you can try this code.

```
<?php

namespace COMPANY\Extension\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
     protected $_scopeConfig;

     public function __construct(ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)  
     {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
     }

     public function getmycustomtax()
     {
        $costarray = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('yoursection/yourgroup/ranges');
        foreach ($costarray as $item) 
        {
            $item['price']; //price is your fields which mension into file.
        }
     }
}
```

Then call `helper` function `getmycustomtax()` when you needed that value.